# Aws Glue Catalog - How not to partition table with glue catalog

Tags: partitioning, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have S3 folder structure of the following format, let's say: Abc/123/xyz.txt and Abc/456/jkl.txt etc.
Where xyz.txt and jkl.txt have same structure.
I am cataloguing it using AWS glue crawler where I am passing the source as: Abc/ and specifying the option of creating a single table for S3 files. What I perceive is that it will create a table with 2 partitions I.e. 123 and 456. But I want to have a single table without any partitioning and contains the data from both xyz.txt and jkl.txt when queried through Atehna. Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Comment: When you query the table created by crawler which contains partitions you should be able to see all the data from all partitions if you are not applying any filter in Athena.If you really don't want any partitions then you can directly create table using DDL in Athena and mentions s3 location as s3://Abc/

Comment: You should use `partition_0` as column name  to fetch 123 and 456 in athena.
You may rename it in Glue Catalog.